# "Gray code" for building teams

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths, gray-codes

**Motivation.** In a team of $n$ people, we had the task to build subteams of a fixed size $k<n$ such that every day, $1$ person of the subteam is replaced by another person in the team, but not in the subteam (so that the new subteam consisted of $k$ again). The question arose if and for what choices of $k$ and $n$ the subteam schedule can be built to contain each choice of $k$ people out of the team exactly once.

**Formal version.** For any set $X$ and positive integer $k$, let $[X]^k$ be the collection of subset of $X$ having $k$ elements. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $[n] =\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For integers $1< k < n$ we define a graph $G(n, k)$ by $V(G(n,k)) = [[n]]^k$ and $$E(G(n,k)) = \big\{\{A, B\} : A, B \in [[n]]^k \land |A\cap B| = k-1\big\}.$$
For what choices of $1< k < n$ does $G(n,k)$ have a Hamiltonian path? Bonus question: Replace "path" by "cycle" in the original question. (The bonus question need not be answered for acceptance.)

Comment: I'll have to go digging to find the specific answer, but this is well-studied and you can find good discussion of it in vol. 4 of Knuth's _Art Of Computer Programming_, on combinatorial algorithms.

Comment: The k=2 version (and variant for n odd) is used in cribbage tournaments with seating arrangements, often where one player is a fixed point and the other 2k-1 form a cycle.  This gives a Gray code of the partitions and not just of the teams.  Gerhard "For Two Player Games, Naturally" Paseman, 2020.06.17.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks @bof (and everybody else)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be possible for all choices of $k$ and $n$. I found a page [here](http://math0.wvstateu.edu/%7Ebaker/cs405/code/RevolvingDoor.html) by Dr. Ronald D. BAKER describing a more than sixty year old 'revolving door algorithm'.

> When enumerating the k-element subsets of and n-set we are implicitly enumerating the partitions of the n-set into parts, one of size s=k and the other of size t=n-k. Hence the problem is often described as the enumeration of (s,t)-combinations. Suppose the think of the set as a collection of people and imagine them being divided into two adjacent rooms, k people in one room with the remaining n-k people in the other room. Now further imagine that there is a **revolving door** connecting the two rooms, and a change consists of an individual from each room entering that revolving door and exchanging sides. This analogy is the source of the moniker revolving door algorithm.
>
> W. H. Payne created the following algorithm in 1959. The call to **visit** might, for example, output the k-subset or it might do the computations of an algorithm which needs all k-element subsets. Each k-subset is referenced by an **index-list**   $c_k \dots c_2c_1$,   the indices of the elements belonging to the subset sorted in order. Notice the code makes extensive use of conditionals, the branching command goto and line labels†.
>
> ```
> algorithm RevDoorSubset(n, k)
>      Array C[1..k+1]
> R1:  for i ← 1 to k do    // initialize C
>         C[i] ← i-1
>      end for
>      C[k+1] ← n
> R2:  visit(C[ ], k)   // Do whatever is needed w/ subset (just print?)
> R3:  if (k is odd)    // the easy cases
>        if ( C[1]+1 < C[2] )                            
>           C[1] ← C[1]+1
>           goto R2
>        else
>            j ← 2
>           goto R4
>        fi
>      else
>        if ( C[1] > 0 )
>           C[1] ← C[1]-1
>           goto R2
>        else
>            j ← 2
>           goto R5
>        fi
>      fi
>     
> R4:  if ( C[j] ≥ j )  // try to decrease C[j]
>        C[j] ← C[j-1]
>        C[j-1] ← j-2
>        goto R2
>      else
>        j ← j+1
>      fi
> R5:  if ( C[j] + 1 < C[j+1] )     // try to increase C[j]
>        C[j-1] ← C[j]
>        C[j] ← C[j] + 1
>        goto R2
>      else
>        j ← j + 1
>        if ( j ≤ k)
>          goto R4
>        fi
>      fi
>      return
> end
> ```

I've converted the algorithm to JavaScript; I don't think MathOverflow supports [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) but I've managed to host a working demo [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327624/295232) in the Sandbox on Meta Stack Exchange. Click the 'Run code snippet' below the code, change the values of $n$ and $k$ and click 'Generate'.

You can also try it online [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Glorfindel83/be7qoj25/6/) in case the Sandbox fails.

It seems this algorithm produces Hamiltonian cycles, but to prove it I'll need some sleep first.

Answer (score 7):

The following recursive description of a revolving door sequence is taken from [here](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ekya17/teaching/math343/15-343.pdf), where it is also proved that it generates a Hamilton cycle. The $k$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ are identified with the bitstrings of length $n$ with exactly $k$ entries equal to $1$. Let $R(k,n)$, denote the binary $\binom{n}{k}\times n$-matrix whose rows correspond to the required sequence of the $k$-sets. Then
$$R(0,n)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\dots&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad R(n,n)=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\dots&1\end{pmatrix},$$
and for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, we obtain $R(k,n)$ by writing down the $\binom{n-1}{k}$ rows of $R(k,n-1)$, putting an additional $0$ in front, and below this writing the $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ rows of $R(k-1,n-1)$ in reverse order, putting an additional $1$ in front.

The precise Knuth reference mentioned in a comment above is Section 7.2.1.3. Generating all combinations in TAOCP, Volume 4A - Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1.

Here's an interesting related result: If $n=2k-1$ then $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}$, and we can hope that in the process every $(k-1)$-set is visited exactly once. That this is possible used to be the middle level conjecture which is now a theorem due to Torsten Mütze: [Proof of the middle levels conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4442). Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 112.4 (2016): 677-713.

Answer (score 6):

**Theorem.** The graph $G(n,k)$ is Hamiltonian if $n\ge3$ and $0\lt k\lt n$.

**Proof.** If $k=1$ or $k=n-1$ it's obvious, because $G(n,k)\cong K_n$ in those cases. Now consider the graph $G=G(n,k)$ where $2\le k\le n-2$. Let
$$S=\{A\in[[n]]^k:1\in A\},\quad S'=\{A\in[[n]]^k:1\notin A\}.$$
Since the induced subgraphs $G[S]$ and $G[S']$ are isomorphic to $G(n-1,k-1)$ and $G(n-1,k)$ respectively, they are Hamiltonian by the inductive hypothesis. Moreover, since the graphs are edge transitive, we can choose a Hamiltonian cycle $C$ in $G[S]$ containing the edge
$$\{A,B\}=\{\{1,\dots,k\},\ \{1,\dots,k-1,k+1\}\}$$
and a Hamiltonian cycle $C'$ in $G[S']$ containing the edge
$$\{A',B'\}=\{\{2,\dots,k,k+2\},\ \{2,\dots,k+1\}\}.$$
Now we get a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$ by removing the edges $\{A,B\}$ and $\{A',B'\}$ from $C\cup C'$, and replacing them with $\{A,A'\}$ and $\{B,B'\}$.

Comment: Note that the graph is also Hamiltonian for $k = 0, n$.

Comment: “By convention, the singleton graph $K_1$ is considered to be Hamiltonian even though it does not posses a Hamiltonian cycle” - https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html

Comment: I would say both the empty and singleton graphs are $n$-connected for any $n$, since deleting any number of edges/vertices leaves them connected, but will admit that I can’t find a reference that agrees with me. :)